# Scope of Exception object when caught(using catch) by reference

Tags: c++, exception

**I have 3 questions :**

**1.** It is always said to catch the exception object by reference. In the following example i see that the destructor is called before the *catch* block executed, that means we are referring to an object in *catch* which must have gone out of scope by the time we use it. Why use reference then?

```
class MyException{
public:
    ~MyException()  {
        cout<<"Dtor for MyException called \n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    try{
        MyException obj1;
        throw obj1;
    }
    catch(MyException& obj)
    {
        cout<<"Catched unhandled exception";
    }
}
```

**2.** Why is the destructor called twice here? Once before entering the *catch* block and second time after execution of *catch* completes.

**3.** The example in [Lifetime of a thrown object caught by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122739/lifetime-of-a-thrown-object-caught-by-reference) shows that the destructor is called just once i.e. after the *catch* block exits ONLY WHEN a *copy constructor* is defined in the class.

**a.** What is the role of copy constructor here when we are catching it by refrence?

**b.** Even after defining a copy constructor it never gets called anyways. So what impact does it make?

**c.** I tried to define a copy constructor in my example too as below but still i see destructor getting called twice.Why?:

```
MyException(const MyException& obj)
{
}
```

Can somebody answer all the 5 questions(3rd question has 3 parts).

Comment: I would recommend defining all of the standard things and rerunning your example to get a better look at what is going on. Default constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment, move constructor, move assignment, and finally destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recommend you take your catch block by reference to avoid slicing (since inheriting exceptions is standard) and to avoid needlessly copying, since `throw` copies unconditionally.

1. You cannot receive `obj1` by reference as `throw obj1` causes it to be destroyed (since it is no longer in scope). Due to this `throw` always copies to temporary memory location that you don't control.
2. `obj1` and the temporary I mentioned before. `obj` is a reference to that temporary, the referenced temporary will be destroyed after the end of the catch block and before the next operation (similar to if it were actually local to the catch block).
3. A single destructor only happens when the copy is elided and the standard doesn't guarantee when that will happen, as copy elision is always optional. Defining a copy constructor makes no difference as the compiler defines it for you if you don't define it (and it can be created). Deleting the copy constructor would just result in `throw` being illegal.

   - a. As above, copy constructor to copy into the temporary. Reference to reference said temporary.
   - b. Did you actually delete the copy constructor? `MyException(const MyException&) = delete;` is how you delete a copy constructor, failing to define it just causes the compiler to make one for you. And to repeat, deleting it causes `throw` to be illegal.
   - c. Because the copy isn't elided and two objects exist, a temporary and your object.

Comment: for 3.c i wanted to say that the behavior of destructor getting called is expected. But why in the other example mentioned in the link, the destructor gets called just once after using copy constructor? It should have got called twice irrespective of a copy ctor is being used or not

Comment: @anurag86: Copy ellision causes the second object to never be created so a second destructor is not called in addition to no copy constructor call.

Answer (score 2):

You're throwing a copy of the exception you created as a local temporary.  So there's two: the first is destroyed when you throw, the second (the copy) after the catch block is done.

Try this:

```
try { throw MyException{}; }
catch (MyException const& obj) { }
```

Edit: If your copy constructor is really not being called in your code then my guess is that the compiler has recognized that the exception class is empty?  Compiler is free to perform any optimizations it chooses so long as the behavior of the code is as-if it hadn't.  Exception to this is copy-ellision but if that was going on you'd not get the double destructor call.

Answer (score 2):

1. `throw` ALWAYS makes a copy of an object you're throwing. You can't throw an object which is not copyable. If fact, `throw` can even fail if it can't allocate enough memory for a copy.
    This should explain why you see a destructor being called inside a `try`-block. It's a destructor of your local `obj1`. It goes out of scope as soon as your throw a copy of it.
   As for catching by reference, it is used to avoid unnecessary copying and, more importantly, potential slicing.
2. Once again, it was a destructor of your local `obj1`. It went after out scope when you threw a copy of it.
3. a) If you catch by reference, no copying is performed. Copying (with potential slicing) is performed ONLY if you catch by value.
   b) You're wrong, `throw` calls a copy constructor to, well, make a copy of your object and throw it. The only case when a copy constructor won't be called is when you throw a temporary object and compiler elides a copy.
   c) Refer to my first and second answer.

Comment: 1. _You can't throw an object which is not copyable_  and _As for catching by reference, it is used to avoid *unnecessary* copying_ . Arent these statements contradicting each other? Secondly, Isnt it meaningless to receive it as reference when throw will always make & send a copy? Lastly, Why does the exmaple in the other post shows that a destructor is called only only after defining a copy ctor.

Comment: One copy is ALWAYS performed by `throw`. After that, if you catch by reference no copying is performed. If you catch by value, a copy is made.

Comment: @anurag86: You always copy once. If you catch by value you slice the exception object (if it is a derived type) and copy twice, once into the temporary and a second time into your value.

Comment: Thanks nikita and Guvante. So if I understand it correctly then throw always will make a copy once unlike regular functions which doesnt create copy if the  receving end is getting it by reference.